# css float select field title on click

Tags: html, css, html-select

I would like to make the select field behave like the other two input fields. After the user fills out the fields, the field title floats on top.
How can I make the select item also behave like the other two input fields? so that by clicking on the field, the placeholder should float to the top.
And the default value shown as the placeholder is **Your Letter**, which will then move up after selecting a letter or clicking on the field.

```css
body {
  font-family: Avenir Next, Avenir, SegoeUI, sans-serif;
}


form {
  margin: 2em 0;
}
.field {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column-reverse;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
label, input {
  transition: all 0.2s;
  touch-action: manipulation;
}
input {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-family: inherit;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: text;
}

input:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
}

label {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}
input:placeholder-shown + label {
  cursor: text;
  max-width: 66.66%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: translate(0, 2.125rem) scale(1.5);
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: inherit;
}
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 1;
}
input:not(:placeholder-shown) + label,
input:focus + label {
  transform: translate(0, 0) scale(1);
  cursor: pointer;
}

 form p select, form p select.selectField {
 width: 195px;
 padding: 1px 3px;
}
```

```html
  <form action="">
  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" placeholder="Jane Appleseed">
    <label for="fullname">Name</label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="field">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="jane.appleseed@example.com">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
  </div>
    <div id="lettersSelection" >
      <p class="required">
        <select name="letters" id="letters" class="selectField" required="">
          <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Your Letter</option>
          <option value="A">Letter A</option>
          <option value="B">Letter B</option>
          <option value="C">Letter C</option>
        </select>
        <label for="letters">Letters</label>
      </p>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: I doesn't understand what do you want...

Comment: Do you want the Letters title move above the drop-down when selected?

Comment: @billy.farroll yes, move it up

Comment: what you want doesn't make sense in terms of UI. please explain better how the title should move. up **where to exactly**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### This **exactly** what you asked for.

I've marked the lines in the *CSS* where changes were made. 
I've also added an extra element to the *HTML*:

```
<span class="placeholder">Your Letter</span>
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Avenir Next, Avenir, SegoeUI, sans-serif;
}

form {
  margin: 2em 0;
}

.field {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column-reverse;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

label{
  display: inline-block; /* <--- needed to have display other than default "inline" */
}

label,
input,
.placeholder{ /* <--- added ".placeholder" */
  transition: .2s;
  touch-action: manipulation;
}

input {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-family: inherit;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: text;
}

input:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
}

label {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}

input:placeholder-shown+label, 
.placeholder { /* <--- added ".placeholder" */
  cursor: text;
  max-width: 66.66%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: translate(0, 2.125rem) scale(1.5);
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: inherit;
}

input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 1;
}

input:not(:placeholder-shown)+label,
input:focus+label {
  transform: none; /* <--- changed to "none" to restore defaults */
  cursor: pointer;
}

form p select,
form p select.selectField {
  width: 195px;
  padding: 5px;  /* <--- bigger value to cover the placeholder text */
}

/* ------- ADDED ------ */
#lettersSelection{ position:relative; margin-top:3em; }

#lettersSelection .placeholder{
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.8rem;
  left: 0;
}

select{ position:relative; z-index:1; }

select:focus + .placeholder{
  transform: none; /* <--- moves the title up on "focus" */
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" placeholder="Jane Appleseed">
    <label for="fullname">Name</label>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="jane.appleseed@example.com">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
  </div>
  
  <div id="lettersSelection">
    <p class="required">
      <select name="letters" id="letters" class="selectField" required>
        <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Your Letter</option>
        <option value="A">Letter A</option>
        <option value="B">Letter B</option>
        <option value="C">Letter C</option>
      </select>
      <span class="placeholder">Your Letter</span>
      <label for="letters">Letters</label>
    </p>
  </div>
</form>
```